# Reading char sent from wireless transmitter and creating switch case

Tags: arduino, char, int, switch-statement

I'm trying to transmit a char wirelessly and have the receiver read that char through serial in order to create a switch statement.

When trying to convert into `int`, I get the same `int` value no matter what char I type into the html text box.  `Serial.print(buffer);` is displaying the right char. All help appreciated.

[image: Script]

This is the char I'm inputting, and the result in the serial

[image: serial]

Answer (score 0):

Let's try this way. After convert "buffer" from "char"-->"int".You can check if h is digital or not before doing something.

```
    //..Your code..//
    //..Your code..//
    //..Your code..//
    int h = (int)buffer;
    if (isDigit(h))
    {
       //Do something;
    }
```